# Variadic function and va_arg : variabilizing the type to be printed

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am trying to recode a `printf` function so I need to use `va_arg` since `printf` is a variadic function.

The thing is, when I want to print out the arguments of `my_printf`, they can be `%i` (`int`) or `%s` (`char *`) if we take these two basic possibilities.

So when I go through my `va_list ap`, I tried to put a variable in the `va_arg` function so I can change the type to be written, like this:

```
char *str = NULL;
str = ft_set_my_types(flags[cur_arg]);          
ft_putstr(va_arg(ap, str));
```

with my function `ft_set_my_types` being something like:

```
char *ft_set_my_types(char *flags)
{
    char **tab = NULL;

    tab = ft_alloc_mem2(2, 15); /* this function malloc a tab */
    char a = 65;

     /* the example here is only with two types of variables */
     /* I am sending flags %s in my example which correspond to "char *" */

    tab['s'] = "char *";
    tab['d'] = "int ";

    size_t len = ft_strlen(flags) - 1;
    while (a < 123)
    {
        if (a == flags[len])
            break ;
        else
            a++;
    }
    return (tab[a]);
}
```

The "char *flags" being everything between the "%" and the flag (included) of `my_printf`.

The problem is: when I compile it does not understand my tab['s'] as `char *` but as "char *" so I get this error:

```
ft_print.c:63:25: error: unknown type name 'str'
                        ft_putstr(va_arg(ap, str));
                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include/stdarg.h:35:50: note:
      expanded from macro 'va_arg'
#define va_arg(ap, type)    __builtin_va_arg(ap, type)
1 error generated.
```

Could you help me to figure out how I can insert my variable `*str` in this `va_arg` function?

Comment: Read the error message. What part of `unknown type name 'str'` do you disagree with?

Comment: Unrelated to your core problem, but I assume that `ft_alloc_mem2(2, 15)` allocates an array of two strings of 15 chars each. If so, your expressions `tab['d']`, `tab['s']` and `tab[a]` have their indices out of range.

Answer (score 5):

C is statically typed.  All data types are determined at compile time.  You cannot obtain the data type for a declaration by calling a function.

Instead, to handle variadic arguments whose type is not known until run time, you must branch based on the selected data type, via a `switch` statement or an `if`/`else if`/`else` nest.  In each alternative, use the `va_arg` macro to obtain the argument, with the appropriate static type handled by that alternative.  You may be able to perform the type-specific processing in helper functions, if you like.

For example,

```
/* ... */
switch (field_code) {
    case 'i':
        do_something_with_int(va_arg(ap, int));
        break;
    case 's':
        do_something_with_string(va_arg(ap, char *));
        break;
    default:
        handle_error();
        break;
}
/* ... */
```

Note that the second argument to `va_arg` is the type itself, not a string representation of it.